# cassandra python " item = val[i] " couldn't figure it out

Tags: python, json, cqlsh, cassandra-driver

I'm new to cassandra python module.So i'm trying to insert a json file into a table using batchstatement.But i'm getting a error of 'KeyError: 0'.I know the provided documents are too much.But i tried alsmost everything and didn't understand my mistake.Please help!!!!!

```
import json
import logging
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
import os
from uuid import uuid4
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, BatchStatement
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from myencoder import MyEncoder
import logging
import re
import ast


def parsing():

    with open('dfs.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        aboutlegacy = data['aboutLegacy']
        accomplishments = data['accomplishments']
        profilealternative = data['profileAlternative']
        educations = data['educations']
        profileLegacy = data['profileLegacy']
        peopleAlsoviewed = data['peopleAlsoViewed']
        positions = data['positions']
        skills = data['skills']
        recommendations = data['recommendations']
        volunteerExperience = data['volunteerExperience']
        profile = data['profile']
        idd = uuid4()


        query = """
        INSERT INTO profile (id,profilelegacy,profilealternative,aboutlegacy,positions,educations,skills,recommendations,accomplishments,peoplealsoviewed,volunteerExperience,profile)
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"""
        insert_user = session.prepare(query)
        batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE)

        batch.add(insert_user, (idd, profileLegacy, profilealternative, aboutlegacy, positions, educations,
                                skills, recommendations, accomplishments, peopleAlsoviewed, volunteerExperience, profile,))
        log = logging.getLogger()
        log.info('Batch Insert Completed')
        session.execute(batch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=9042)
    session = cluster.connect('profiles', wait_for_all_pools=True)
    session.execute('USE profiles')
    parsing()
```

this the error produced :

```
File "cassandratest2.py", line 61, in <module>
    parsing()
  File "cassandratest2.py", line 51, in parsing
    skills, recommendations, accomplishments, peopleAlsoviewed, volunteerExperience, profile,))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\query.py", line 815, in add
    bound_statement = statement.bind(() if parameters is None else parameters)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\query.py", line 501, in bind
    return BoundStatement(self).bind(values)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\query.py", line 627, in bind
    self.values.append(col_spec.type.serialize(value, proto_version))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cqltypes.py", line 723, in serialize
    return cls.serialize_safe(val, protocol_version)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cqltypes.py", line 942, in serialize_safe
    item = val[i]
KeyError: 0
```

this is the json file just the format because it contains confidential infos

```
{
    "profileLegacy": {
        "name": "",
        "headline": "",
        "location": "",
        "connections": 0,
        "summary": ""
    },
    "profileAlternative": {
        "name": "",
        "headline": "",
        "location": "",
        "connections": 0
    },
    "aboutLegacy": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "positions": [{
        "org": "",
        "title": "",
        "end": "",
        "start": "",
        "desce": ""
    }],
    "educations": [{
        "major": "",
        "end": "",
        "name": "",
        "degree": "Maestr\u00eda en Finanzas",
        "start": "",
        "desce": ""
    }],
    "skills": [
        "Key Account Development",
        "Strategic Planning"
    ],
    "recommendations": {
        "givenCount": "0",
        "receivedCount": "0",
        "given": [],
        "received": []
    },
    "accomplishments": [],
    "peopleAlsoViewed": [{
        "url": "",
        "id": ""
    }],
    "volunteerExperience": [],
    "profile": {
        "name": "",
        "headline": "",
        "location": "",
        "connections": 0
    }
}
```

this the create table query in cqlsh

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    profilelegacy frozen<profilelegacy>,
    profilealternative  frozen<profilelaternative>,
    aboutlegacy text,
    positions list<frozen<positions>>,
    educations set<frozen<educations>>,
    skills list<text>,
    recommendations frozen<recommendations>,
    accomplishments list<text>,
    peoplealsoviewed list<frozen<peoplealsoviewed>>,
    volunteerExperience list<text>,
    profile frozen<profilelaternative>
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
and these are the declared types

CREATE TYPE profiles.peoplealsoviewed (
    url text,
    id text
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.profilelegacy (
    name text,
    headline text,
    location text,
    connections int,
    summary text
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.positions (
    org text,
    title text,
    end text,
    start text,
    desce text
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.recommendations (
    givencount text,
    receivedcount text,
    given frozen<list<text>>,
    received frozen<list<text>>
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.skills (
    title text,
    count text
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.educations (
    major text,
    end text,
    name text,
    degree text,
    start text,
    desce text
);

CREATE TYPE profiles.profilelaternative (
    name text,
    headline text,
    location text,
    connections int
);
```

Answer (score 1):

When Cassandra is trying to populate based on user defined types, it expects either a `tuple` of values in the same order as the type's fields, e.g. for `profilelegacy`, it wants `(name, headline, location, connections, summary)`, *or* an object with attributes matching the names in question (e.g. some object `x` for which is can retrieve `x.name`, then `x.headline`, etc.).

You're loading a JSON file, which decodes JSON objects as Python `dict`s (which use key based lookup), not Python objects (which use attribute based lookup). You need to convert from the `dict` to either the appropriate `tuple` or an object with the appropriate attributes.

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to [use `types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) to let you make objects from arbitrary `dict`s. Importing `types` and changing your `json.load` to something like:

```
data = json.load(json_file, object_hook=lambda d: types.SimpleNamespace(**d))
```

with lookups in the result changed from `dict`-style to object-style:

```
aboutlegacy = data.aboutLegacy
accomplishments = data.accomplishments
# ... etc ...
```

should get you much closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I’m trying to deep searching for simplenamespace and i’ll post my progress

Comment: i found another solution using namedtuple module  from collections   import namedtuple  then```profilealt = data["profileAlternative"]
        profilealternative = namedtuple(
            "profileAlternative", profilealt.keys())(*profilealt.values()) ```